# Throw same error format as `class-validator` in NestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

Let's have this controller in NestJS project:

```
  @Post('resetpassword')
  @HttpCode(200)
  async requestPasswordReset(
    @Body() body: RequestPasswordResetDTO,
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      return await this.authService.requestPasswordReset(body);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e instanceof EntityNotFoundError) {
        // Throw same exception format as class-validator throwing (ValidationError)
      } else throw e;
    }
  }
```

Dto definition:

```
export class RequestPasswordResetDTO {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEmail()
  public email!: string;
}
```

I want to throw error in `ValidationError` format (property, value, constraints, etc) when `this.authService.requestPasswordReset(body);` throws an `EntityNotFoundError` exception.

How I can create this error manually? Those errors are just thrown when DTO validation by `class-validator` fails. And those can be just static validations, not async database validations.

So the final API response format should be for example:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": [
        {
            "target": {
                "email": "not@existing.email"
            },
            "value": "not@existing.email",
            "property": "email",
            "children": [],
            "constraints": {
                "exists": "email address does not exists"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need it to have consistent error handling :)

Comment: You can create an async validator. See example here: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-decorators

Answer (score 26):

When adding the `ValidationPipe` to your app, provide a custom `exceptionFactory`:

```
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      exceptionFactory: (validationErrors: ValidationError[] = []) => {
        return new BadRequestException(validationErrors);
      },
    })
  );
```

This should be all you need to get the intended result.

For comparison, you can check out the original NestJS version [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/4ebe4504b938faff615a9c95abc4a185419e304c/packages/common/pipes/validation.pipe.ts#L118).

Comment: I think at one point NestJs use to always return ValidationErrors, but in the latest version they defaulted to their own exception filter.  I could be wrong, but I did have an array of ValidationErrors coming across at one point. That or I changed the config somewhere.

Comment: And how do you access the values?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, @John. Inside the exception factory arrow function, the raw validation errors from `class-validator` can be accessed in the `validationErrors` variable.

Comment: You may need to concatenate the constraints to pass into the Exception constructor to see the validation descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [Exception Filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#exception-filters-1) to create your customized response to that exception
First we define the Exception Filter:

```js
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, ArgumentsHost, HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
// import { EntityNotFoundError } from 'wherever';

@Catch(EntityNotFoundError)
export class EntityNotFoundExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
    const status = exception.getStatus();

    response
      .status(status)
      .json({
        "statusCode": 400,
        "error": "Bad Request",
        "message": [
          {
            "target": {},
            "property": "email",
            "children": [],
            "constraints": {
              "isEmail": "email must be an email"
            }
          },
          // other field exceptions
        ]
      });
  }
}
```

Then back in your controller, you use the filter:

```js
  // ...
  import { EntityNotFoundExceptionFilter } from 'its module';
  // ...
  @Post('resetpassword')
  @HttpCode(200)
  @UseFilters(EntityNotFoundExceptionFilter)
  async requestPasswordReset(
    @Body() body: RequestPasswordResetDTO
  ): Promise<boolean> {
      return await this.authService.requestPasswordReset(body);
  }
```

This should work just fine.

Comment: `EntityNotFoundError` is not same as `HttpException`, your example will fail on `exception.getStatus()`

Comment: This is pretty bad. You would need to create a custom exception filter for every single error message in class-validator. That would be like 30+ exception filters. No thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can get back the exception response thrown by `class-validator` and set to response,

```js
import {
  ArgumentsHost,
  BadRequestException,
  Catch,
  ExceptionFilter
} from '@nestjs/common';

@Catch()
export class ValidationFilter < T > implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch (exception: T, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    if (exception instanceof BadRequestException) {
      const response = host.switchToHttp().getResponse();
      response.status(exception.getStatus())
        .json(exception.getResponse());
    }
  }
}
```

Controller should look,

```js
@Post('create')
@UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
@UseFilters(ValidationFilter)
async create(@Body() body: CreateDto) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extend the default validation pipe and overwrite the `createExceptionFactory` function:

```js
import {
  ValidationError,
  ValidationPipe as NestValidationPipe,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpErrorByCode } from '@nestjs/common/utils/http-error-by-code.util';

export class ValidationPipe extends NestValidationPipe {
  public createExceptionFactory() {
    return (validationErrors: ValidationError[] = []) => {
      if (this.isDetailedOutputDisabled) {
        return new HttpErrorByCode[this.errorHttpStatusCode]();
      }
      return new HttpErrorByCode[this.errorHttpStatusCode](validationErrors);
    };
  }
}
```

What this does is just to remove a single line of code from the default ValidationPipe that converts the errors:
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/4ebe4504b938faff615a9c95abc4a185419e304c/packages/common/pipes/validation.pipe.ts#L123

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old and the OP has probably moved on, but I keep hitting it as the top search result, and from my understanding, no-one has addressed the OP's question.  I have the same requirement.  I need to throw an Exception in the same format as class validators validation exceptions.  For that purpose, I created a custom exception class:

```js
import { BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';

export class ValidationException extends BadRequestException {
  constructor(
    propertyName: string,
    message: string,
    constraintName = 'custom',
    originalData = {},
  ) {
    // wrap arguments in the correct error format
    super([
      {
        target: originalData,
        property: propertyName,
        value: originalData[propertyName] || null,
        children: [],
        constraints: {
          [constraintName]: message,
        },
      },
    ]);
  }
}
```

Then whenever I need to throw an exception from my controller, I can do:

```js
@NoAuth()
  @Post('login')
  async signIn(@Body() signInDto: LoginUserDto): Promise<ApiResponse> {

    if (isNotFoo(signInDto.email)){
        throw new ValidationException(
          'email',
          'Email is not FOO!',
          'mustBeFoo', // optional, will default to custom
          signInDto, // optional, include it if your front-end relies on the 'target' field, or the 'value' field of the response
        );
    }
    
  }
```